# Nestjs BasicStrategy doesnt accept empty password

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport

I try to implement basic authentication in nestjs like:

```
@Injectable()
export class BasicStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'basic') {
    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
        super({
            passReqToCallback: true,
        });
    }

    public validate = async (req, username, password): Promise<boolean> => {
        const keys = this.configService.get<string>('SECURE_KEY').split(',');
        if (
            keys[0] === username
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
}
```

When I send request with username: ... and password: "", it gives unauthorized error. Is there a solution for it? Any suggestion?[image]

Comment: are you sending an empty string? also, see if the `validate` method is being invoked

Comment: @MicaelLevi it is blank string. validate method is not invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`passport-http` expects the password to be sent](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http/blob/master/lib/passport-http/strategies/basic.js#L82). If you want to be able to have it blank, you'll need your own custom strategy